# Use of aggregate function with multiple projections

Tags: sql, postgresql

Having trouble knowing my options when I am wanting to use aggregate functions with multiple columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.bankname, b.city, a.robberydate
FROM banks b, accomplices a
WHERE a.city = 'Chicago' and b.city ='Chicago' and b.bankname = a.bankname;
```

This is my query so far.

In the accomplices table, there is a 'shares' column which holds the shares that the robber got. I am wanting to get the average share of each robbery.

When I try to use AVG(shares), it says I need to set the selected columns as being GROUPED BY or part of a aggregate function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.bankname, b.city, a.robberydate, AVG(shares)
FROM banks b, accomplices a
WHERE a.city = 'Chicago' and b.city ='Chicago' and b.bankname = a.bankname;
```

What are some common ways to going about problems like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by the columns you want to be unique and use aggregate functions for the rest of the columns you want to display

```
SELECT b.bankname, b.city, a.robberydate, AVG(shares)
FROM banks b
join accomplices a on b.bankname = a.bankname
WHERE a.city = 'Chicago' and b.city ='Chicago'
group by b.bankname, b.city, a.robberydate
```

Comment: That is odd. I previously tried adding a group by for all of them and it gave me a error. Now i tried again and it worked fine :). Is there any benefit doing the join's that you did over my joins?

Comment: Can I have as many attributes in group by as I wish? Or is there a constraint or what can go in it?

Comment: @user2469515: using explicit `JOIN` operator is preferred over the outdated implicit joins in the `where` clause for various reasons. First: you can't specify an outer join using the outdated syntax. Second: it prevents you of accidentally missing a join condition because it will then throw a syntax error rather than doing a cross join. And finally (but that's my personally opinion) they make the statement clearer because join (=join) conditions and filter conditions (=where) are clearly separated